# Web API Session

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.net Application which delivers most of the main interface but then is heavily driven by Javascript as its mostly a tabbed based application which retrieves data via Web API and changes Div content.

This is going to be a cloud based solution, so multiple customers connect and it stores data in their own database.

Now I would like to secure the Web API for two reasons.

1. Security, so it knows who should be access what data
2. Access, so it knows which database it should be connecting to

At the moment, I handle my own authentication with my own tables for users and groups.

What is the best way to handle the Web API side to work with this?

i thought about storing a unique session ID against an Active Users table when they login, then this token/id gets passed as a parameter when the Web API is called, the Web API then checks if this token exists in the Active Users table and if so either retrievs the permissions the user/group and also checks which database it should be connecting to.

Does this sound like it would work or is there a better approach I am overlooking?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you're trying to reinvent [ASP.Net Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started) framework.

Answer (score 0):

I would add authentication filter in WebApi Configuration and add Authorize attribute in Web API methods. For accessing users session you may use the below code.

```
    protected void Application_PostAuthorizeRequest()
    {
        if(IsWebAPIRequest())
        {
            HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.Required);
        }
    } 

    private bool IsWebAPIRequest()
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath.StartsWith("~/api");
    }
```

Based on users' session id you may choose which database to connect.